# CiviCRM on Wamp server over lan network

Tags: civicrm.settings.php

I want to access civiCRM in my organization's LAN network. Can anyone give a link or simplify the process to me? googling gives me many options, don't know which to try . using wamp server. Apache version 2.4.23 ; wamp server 3.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites) looks like a fairly comprehensive guide to allowing network access to your Wamp sites over a LAN.